# replace all images with div background element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' );
for( i = 0; i < all.length; i++ ){
    var newimg;
    (newimg=document.createElement('div')).style.cssText="display:inline;width:"+all[i].width+"px;height:"+all[i].width+"px;background-image:url("+all[i].src+");";
    all[i].parentNode.replaceChild( newimg, all[i] );
}
```

replaces only two images (1 and 3) out of 4 example images (test1.jpg to test4.jpg) and also doesn't display any div backgrounds.
am i doing this wrong?

generated output result so far:

```
<div style="display: inline; width: 400px; height: 400px; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost/test1.jpg&quot;);"></div> 
<img src="test2.jpg">
<div style="display: inline; width: 796px; height: 796px; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost/test3.jpg&quot;);"></div> 
<img src="test4.jpg">
```

thanks!

Comment: is it really replacing your double-quotes with &quot; entities? or is that just a stackoverflow formatting artifact?

Comment: no there are no quotes - if you would write into the code url('"+url+"') - the generated output would be the same. i guess the renderer in javascript just adds that by default.

Comment: cssText="background-image:url("+all[i].src+");"; same outcome as: cssText="background-image:url('"+all[i].src+"');"; or: cssText="background-image:url(\""+all[i].src+"\");";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`View live demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/ChinmayeeG/EMkgf/3/)**

You have to iterate loop in reverse direction. Since each time you replace img, length of **all** array decreases by one. hence you are not able to access all[1], all[3] elements.

Also due `display:inline`, other css text (height/width/background/) image is not applying to your div, so remove it and use `float:left` instead.

Hope this will help.

Comment: any ideas how to make the div behave exactly the same as an image tag? float:left kinda breaks the whole thing... ;)

Comment: You can still use float:left, just set height of div = height of image [instead of width], remove border, add margin [if needed] and set background-repeat to no repeat. See updated link http://jsfiddle.net/ChinmayeeG/EMkgf/3/

Comment: use <img src="/img/logo.png"/><br /> and you'll see the significant difference

Comment: i saw inline-block works pretty much as it should but is that cross browser compatible?

Comment: inline-block is supported by all major browser. But it seems that empty div does not shows its CSS properties in that case.